# Timeout error when using Pycharm Debugger

Tags: pycharm, pyramid, remote-debugging

My Pycharm debugger config for my Pyramid web app works well, though I get timeout errors when I stay to long on a breakpoint. How can I avoid getting this (traceback below), and keep debugging in peace ?

```
[2016-05-02 10:13:39 +0000] [5203] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:5218)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 490, in trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 67, in do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 712, in do_wait_suspend
    time.sleep(0.01)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 159, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
Error - <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>: 1
[2016-05-02 10:13:39 +0000] [5218] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5218)
Exiting 0 (-v to see traceback)
^C[2016-05-02 10:13:40 +0000] [5203] [INFO] Handling signal: int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 336, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using gunicorn (WORKER TIMEOUT looks like gunicorn to me) try setting a timeout in your ini file (whichever config file you are pointing PyCharm to):

```
[server:gunicorn]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 1234
workers = 4
timeout = 9999
```

Comment: No problem, please this as the answer if it helped you out!

Comment: @eton_ceb as another note, make sure you either set the timeout in a development only config (recommended) or just remember to drop the timeout before deploying to a production machine.

Comment: yep, thanks, I have separate config files. Thx for the heads-up